# Insert / paste before cursor in Audacity?

Tags: audacity

Is there a way to insert / paste audio before the position of the cursor in Audacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/edit_menu_copy_paste_and_duplicate.html

If you're creative, there is a way (not very practical though):

1. reverse the audio, both destination track and the source you copy from
2. mark and copy reversed material in source
3. place marker and paste in destination
4. reverse destination track again